# initializing a multidimensional array using size of another array without coping the elements in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

i want to initialize an array from another multidimensional array. The thing is i don't want the elements, the second array only needs to be the same size.

like i have

```
int table[1][2];
table[0][0] = '1';
table[0][1] = '2';
table[0][2] = '3';
table[1][0] = '4';
table[1][1] = '5';
table[1][2] = '6';
}
```

and i need:

```
 int copyofthetable[1][2];

    copyofthetable[0][0] = '0';
    copyofthetable[0][1] = '0';
    copyofthetable[0][2] = '0';
    copyofthetable[1][0] = '0';
    copyofthetable[1][1] = '0';
    copyofthetable[1][2] = '0';
```

i have tried arraycopy but it copies the elements as well. note that i don't have the size of the first array beforehand and its given later.
thanks :)

Comment: Try `table.length` and `table[0].length` (assuming the first `length` is > 0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need an array of the same size :

```
int[][] copyofthetable = new int[table.length][table[0].length];
```

This is assuming all the rows of the `table` array have the same length. If that's not the case, you'll need a loop :

```
int[][] copyofthetable = new int[table.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
    copyofthetable[i] = new int[table[i].length];
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only work if the table[0].length is the same as table[1].length?

Comment: @Turtle Yep, I just added a comment about that.

Comment: @Turtle according to how the question was asked (at least in the example provided) it would be. Good observation nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks @Eran!
I was just wondering if looping is the most efficient way as there are some complexity checks later on in our system.

Comment: @user1972584 You have no other choice if your source 2D array has rows of varying lengths. If you use `System.arraycopy`, you will be copying references of the original inner arrays (the rows of the original array), so even if you didn't mind copying the int values, you'd still have a problem (since `target[1][2]=3` would also modify `source[1][2]`).